# jQuery / Javascript replace <space> in anchor link with %20

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I'm new to jQuery and i'm trying to write some code to go through the page and rewrite anchor links href attribute so that spaces are removed and replaced with %20.

so far i have:

```
$(".row a").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("href").replace(/\s/g,"%20");
});
```

I've tried a few variations of this with no luck.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but you're forgetting to set the new value once you replace it. Try this:

```
$(".row a").each( function() {
   this.href = this.href.replace(/\s/g,"%20");
});
```

Comment: Just a note since I was beating my head trying to figure this out. I use the HTML Validator add-on for Firefox and it was still reporting whitespace in URI references. This is because the validator parses the page separately, *without* JavaScript.

Answer (score 22):

You'd be better off using the native javascript [`encodeURI`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp) function.

```
$(".row a").each(function(){
  $(this).attr( 'href', encodeURI( $(this).attr("href") ) );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the attribute value ( [`attr(key, value)`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr) ), in your code you are only reading its value:

```
$(".row a").each(function(){
  $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr("href").replace(/\s/g,"%20"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@Naresh
Yes there is a way for that, see the below example:

Decode a URI after encoding it:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var uri="my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
document.write(encodeURI(uri)+ "<br />");
document.write(decodeURI(uri));

</script>
```

---

The output of the code above will be:

---

```
my%20test.asp?name=st%C3%A5le&car=saab
my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab
```

---

for more details visit [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeURI.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `""` like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#content a").each(function (){
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr("href").replace("%20",""));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super late, but I found that the `unescape()` method tends to work too...

Answer (score 0):

in ES2021 use replaceAll()

```
 $(".row a").each( function() {
        this.href = this.href.replaceAll('',"%20");
    });
```