# How can I replace Space with %20 in javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [jQuery / Javascript replace <space> in anchor link with %20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853804/jquery-javascript-replace-space-in-anchor-link-with-20)

I am getting sParameter like this :

`sParameter = document.getElementById('ddParameterType').value;`

If I am getting word like `"Test - Text"` as the ddParameterType item, then I am replacing the space in word  like below:

`sParameter = document.getElementById('ddParameterType').value.replace("","%20");`

but it is returning a valur like `%20Test - Text`.
 I need like `Test%20-%20Text`.

Comment: there is encodeURI: http://stackoverflow.com/a/853872/14955

Comment: I am sorry, I am unable to understand the need for you to encode user data. Can anyone help me understand the reason for this?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
sParameter = encodeURIComponent(sParameter.trim()) //"Test%20-%20Text"
```

the [`.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) will remove leading and trailing whitespace from the string. `encodeURIComponent` will URL-encode it.

Comment: this solution works in IE and other browsers. thanks

Comment: encodeURIComponent() changes http:// into something like http%3A%2F%2F and its not working on browsers.

Comment: encodeURI is the prefer way to retain http:// protocol

Answer (score 21):

replace `replace("","%20");` with `replace(/ /g,"%20");`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: This is correct answer but it's of poor quality. The right thing to do is to use `encodeURIComponent()`

Comment: encodeURIComponent() changes http:// into something like http%3A%2F%2F and its not working on browsers. this is better than the accepted answer

Comment: True, I am working with Google Custom Search and Encode URI component made the API call not work for me

Answer (score 10):

```
 sParameter = encodeURIComponent(sParameter.trim())
```

Comment: Note this does a lot more than just spaces... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent But that is probably a good thing.

Answer (score 5):

Use the following instead to replace *all* occurrences:

```
document.getElementById('ddParameterType').value.replace(/ /g, "%20");
```

Or better [yet](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp):

```
encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('ddParameterType').value);
```